# How does Adobe Reader in Win11 automatically open PDF files downloaded by Google Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, adobe-reader

I have a Google Chrome in Win11 with no Adobe Extensions (as far as I know)
But when I download a PDF from a gmail (attachment) it suddenly opens in Adobe Acrobat without any further action from my side..

how does this work? I tried to search for any Adobe extension or plugin in chrome but nothing..

There is an option in Adobe to "Open PDFs automatically in Reader when they are downloaded in Chrome browser"
[image: the showcase of Adobe reader settings with the option to auto open the PDF]

the adobe reader version should be 23.8.20458.0
[image: exe properties]

Comment: This is a great question that I really want to know the answer to!

Answer (score 0):

It seems the setting is managed by HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Adobe\Adobe Acrobat\DC\AutoDocOpen --> bIsAutoDocOpenFeatureEnabled --> DWORD 1.
It seems to be outside the intended behavior for Google Chrome as no documentation exist for it within Googles docs.
To be honest, this kind of browser hijacking is malware like behavior not acceptable from compagnies like Adobe.

https://community.adobe.com/t5/acrobat-discussions/pdf-downloaded-from-chrome-automatically-opening-in-acrobat-reader/td-p/14181039

Answer (score -1):

The new browsers have native support to open pdf file.
I have seen it happen with MS Edge, too.

I have a few machines that do not have Adobe Reader installed on them, whenever I need to open a pdf file, I just drag them on the already opened browser window and it does the trick.

Comment: Yeah, but the PDF file doesn't open in the browser; it opens in Acrobat Reader.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1241884)